# TwitterKit occasionally returning nil session for existing users

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

When a user opens my app, the login flow goes like this:

1. Start TwitterKit with `Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: consumerKey, consumerSecret: consumerSecret)`.
2. Start Fabric with `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Twitter.self])`.
3. Check for an existing session with `Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()`.
4. If there is no existing session, allow them to login with `Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn(withMethods: TWTRLoginMethod.webBasedForceLogin)`.

I'm seeing an intermittent problem where quite frequently, a user will open the app, after having previously logged in, and there won't be an existing session - it'll return nil, so they're asked to login again. But then if they quit the app or cancel the new login, then start the app again, the existing session is returned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to save session with `saveSession` method like below

```
func saveSession(session: TWTRSession) {
    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.save(session) { (session, error) in
        print(session)
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```